# How to select * and calculate field in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to select all pictures and calculate IsAnnotated field, but how I can select * fields and apply this IsAnnotated field?
Because in this example for now only selected IsAnnotated. Do we have a possibility to prevent manually write something like Id = picture.Id, title = picture.Title?

```
var picture = await _dbContext.Pictures
                .Select(picture => new Picture
                {
                    IsAnnotated = _dbContext.Annotations.Any(x => x.PictureId == picture.Id),
                })
                .Where(s => ids.Contains(s.Id))
                .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: You should do the `Where` first, instead of the `Select`

Comment: 'where' will return the Pictures that has eny annotatin but didnt change "IsAnnotated"field

Comment: Do you have a navigation property? `_dbContext.Pictures.Where(p => p.Annotations.Any())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, select the Pictures you want by ids list:

```
 var pictures = _dbContext.Pictures
            .Where(s => ids.Contains(s.Id));
```

Second, calculate the IsAnnotated field with foreach - this is not a case of 'select', this is an update case. (Convert to 'List' for using the ForEach linq function, you can use the foreach statement instead):

```
pictures.ToList().ForEach(a => a.IsAnnotated = _dbContext.Annotations.Any(x => x.PictureId == a.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
    Var pictures = _dbcontext.Pictures.Where(x=> IDs.Contains(x.id));

var annotations = await pictures.Join(_dbContext.annotation, pic => pic.id, ann => ann.pictureId, (pic, ann) => new 
    {
       Annotation = ann.IsAnnotated
    }.ToListAsync();
```

Or instead an anonymous type you can pass a model if you want.

Sorry if it's not readable but I wrote it from my phone!!